# How to retrieve data without database or files?

Tags: node.js, database, file, no-database

I'm a Node.js developer, recently I attended an interview. There the interviewer asked me below mentioned question

> How to retrieve data without database or files?

For example:

A company named ABC, there is a separate Microsoft Teams. Which contains the name and phone number of the employees. If there is a sudden internet issue or database crash, how will you fetch the details of the employee without database or files available?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a good place for this type of questions, please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @Molda: Yes I understood, but this is based on technical question and also knowledge sharing correct. `stackoverflow` is best please to share the knowledge.